# C# method to return var

Tags: c#, return, var

I like to return var from my method.
I manage to use dynamic, but then my try-catch-finally does not work.
Could you improve my method to return var?
I do not need to use dynamic, I am looking for the best method to return var.

Thank you so much in advance.
Rune

```
public dynamic m_DEMO_Return_var_method(string vpSchemaName, string vpTableName)
{

    var var_List = new List<string>();

    //try
    //{

    DataTable iDataTable = new DataTable();

    var_List.Clear();
    foreach (DataRow iDataRow in iDataTable.Rows)
    {
        var_List.Add(iDataRow["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
    }

    var vColumnName = var_List.ToArray();

    return vColumnName;

    //}
    //catch (Exception im_Exception)
    //{
    //    return vColumnName;
    //}
    //finally
    //{
    //}
}
```

Comment: you can't return var. What type would it be....?

Comment: why you need to return var? why not return an array? or use generics?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to return var. var is typed when the code is compiled. Returning var would be confusing.

Comment: You may benefit from describing what exactly you're trying to do with this method. You're actually always returning a `string[]` according to your last line, it's unclear why you can't just use that as the return type.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17503153/952310](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17503153/952310)

Comment: @MitchWheat, whatever type the compiler would have assigned the variable `y` if `return x;` were replaced with `var y = x;` and using the same rules as `new [] { a, b, c, }` for automatically calculating the array’s type when there are multiple `return` statements in the function. Of course it wouldn’t be useful in all situations, but there are some time when it would be nice…

Comment: @bikini: the goal of code is to be clear. That would not aid reading and understanding code IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can update your code as follows.

```
public dynamic m_DEMO_Return_var_method(string vpSchemaName, string vpTableName)
{

    var var_List = new List<string>();
    var vColumnName = var_List.ToArray();
    try
    {

        DataTable iDataTable = new DataTable();

        var_List.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow iDataRow in iDataTable.Rows)
        {
            var_List.Add(iDataRow["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
        }

        vColumnName = var_List.ToArray();

        return vColumnName;

    }
    catch (Exception im_Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
    }

    return vColumnName;
}
```

The method will return null if vColumnName variable will not contain any data or if any exception will occure.

Comment: NICE!!! I needed a string array, but I did not know the size of the array, so I selected var List<string>; but ended up with return problems...Thank You! You Rock!

Comment: @RBrattas, You do not need to return `dynamic` to return an array of unknown size. Every time `dynamic` pops up, you’re putting method resolution, etc., of to runtime which makes for more confusing failures. It would be much better to have your method just return `string[]` or even `IEnumerable<string>` or `List<string>`.

Answer (score 8):

> Could you improve my method to return var? I do not need to use
>   dynamic, I am looking for the best method to return var.

`var` is not a type but a C# keyword for shortening and making the code more readable (an implicitly typed local variable) - read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) about it more deeply. So forget about returning `var` - Use a real type in your method signature, just like: `int`, `string` etc.

As it's looked now, you're returning `string` array, so change the return type to `string[]`, look:

```
public string[] m_DEMO_Return_var_method(string vpSchemaName, string vpTableName)
```

As for the `try-catch-finally` block, it would not work for you because `vColumnName` is declared in the `try` scope (code block) - You can always declare it higher, in the method scope for example.

BTW, you're just instanciating the DataTable but not filling it first, where should the data come from?:

```
DataTable iDataTable = new DataTable();
```

You're also clearing the `var_List` without filling it first:

```
var_List.Clear();
```

In addition, you're better use another name for your method name, as the accepted convention in c# is Pascal case for methods naming:

```
GetVarMethod
```

Comment: Frustrates me more and more that this isn't possible - as typescript adds more and more clever functionality of a similar nature. There are obviously complexities to implementing this (like cross assembly issues), but there's no reason why a function couldn't return its anonymous type as a 'var' and pass on the definition to whatever calls it. The type may be anonymous but it exists in the CLR as a real type! The compiler can figure it out from there. Certain limitations are fine - I'd be fine if this was limited to being internal to a class. I really hope someday we can get this.

Comment: However... there are now tuples in C# 7 which allows you to create statically typed 'types' in place that can be returned from a method (or even used as a generic type parameter). They can offer some similarities to creating anonymous types that can alleviate the need for `var` as I said earlier. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Answer (score 6):

The type of the object that you are returning is always `string[]`. You could change the return type of your method without affecting its functionality:

```
public string[] m_DEMO_Return_var_method(string vpSchemaName, string vpTableName)
```

This would still allow you to use `var` when calling the method:

```
var result = m_DEMO_Return_var_method("schema", "table");
```

**Edit**: Your `catch` block isn't compiling because you're attempting to return a variable, `vColumnName`, that is not declared within its scope. You can fix this by returning `null` or an empty `string[]`.

```
catch
{
    return null;
    // return new string[0];   // (alternative)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Var cannot be used as method return value neither as method parameter.Since you are returning a collection you can make your return type IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<T> m_DEMO_Return_var_method<T>(string vpSchemaName, string vpTableName)
{
     .......

     .......

     return vColumnName as IEnumerable<T>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the return type of the method to object and you can return anything declared using the var keyword whatever type it happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question of "returning var" it does solve your problem, similar answers exist above but applying a method I use often to your exact code:

```
     public string[] demo(string vpSchemaName, string vpTableName)
     {
        List<string> string_List = new List<string>();

        DataTable iDataTable = new DataTable();

        foreach (DataRow iDataRow in iDataTable.Rows)
        {
            string_List.Add(iDataRow["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
        }

        return string_List.ToArray();
    }
```